# Javascript onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, events

On running below code, getting following error - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById("x").onclick = function() {
alert("clicked the button");
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="x">this is button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the element by id because the document is not loaded.

try to add onload function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("x").onclick = function() {
    alert("clicked the button");
  };
};
```

Comment: this solution is fine. But I have additional suggestion that you should put the <script></script> after the <body/> element. Please google it you will find out why.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to bind the click event before the button exists in the DOM.  Either move your click event binding to the bottom of your body, of change it as follows:

`<button id="x" onClick="alert('clicked the button');">this is button</button>`

Cheers,
autoboxer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an event listener:

```
var button = document.getElementById('x');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('button clicked');    
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null is the error being thrown. I am running the above code in w3school editor.

Comment: a... durp... indeed, your trying to get to the DOM before its ready. move your script out of the head and into the end of the body

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate your `<script>` element after `<button>`. The error is thrown because `getElementById` returns `null` as it could not find the element `#x` as the `button#x` element had not been yet reached at that point of time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <button id="x">this is button</button>
    <script>
       document.getElementById("x").onclick = function() {
           alert("clicked the button");
       };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working! will accept your answer in a bit. Please explain how is it making a difference. Mine looks fine, right:?

Comment: Because the dom is not  load ready when you get the element, so you cannot get the button dom in the script. The correct way is write script tag after the dom, or write the get element method in window.onload.

Comment: @kenticny I think you were replying to the OP, in that case please use the `@` mention because instead I got notified :)